# two behaviors for org-return-follows-link

Tags: org-mode, org-link

In my org-mode config I have activated `org-return-follows-link` to access links with the return key. For instance, if a link points to a pdf, I have configured org-mode to open it with certain pdf viewer (Skim in Mac OS).

Would it be possible to change the behavior of `org-return-follows-link` if, for instance, the *shift* key is pressed when I hit return on a link to a pdf file in org-mode? I think to the possibility to open the same file with another application than the one above. I don't think `org-file-apps`is directly suited for this and I don't see where to start.

The reason of this question is the following. I have inserted vector pdf figures in an org-mode document generating a nice PDF while I export it. Occasionally, I like to edit these figures with Inkscape. However, since I don't want to open all pdf with inkscape, I'd like to ask org-mode to open pdf with inkscape only if the shift key modifier is pressed while I'm pressing return on the link of this pdf image, keeping the normal behavior for any other pdf in any other org-mode documents (that are not all figures).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ... another possibility if this is possible is to get two different behaviors for opening a folder pointed by a link, for instance normal opening in a dired buffer with the return key, and opening in Finder if shift+return.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `S-RET` only exists under a graphical environment. If you ever run Emacs in a console/terminal, things like that will *not* work: `RET` and `S-RET` will not be different. But if you are willing to accept that, then I think it's possible.